# create complex scrolling view in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollview

there!

Can anyone achieve something like this in flutter?

[screen recorded video](https://i.ibb.co/7j22Mjy/ezgif-1-c9a215c5e5.gif) (file size too big to attach it here!)

Comment: We still can't see the video, could you please tell us what do you mean by complex scrolling view

Comment: @TimurTurbil i have updated the video, sorry about that!

Comment: You can achieve this by using showModalBottomSheet widget

Comment: @TimurTurbil but the widget you saw is part of the scrolling view, i tried CustomScrollView widget but didn't get the same results!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the AppBar's color by using `ScrollController#addListener.`

It's a simple implementation with RiverPod.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class CustomScrollViewSample extends ConsumerWidget {
  const CustomScrollViewSample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      controller: ref.read(controller),
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: ref.watch(backgroundColor),
          foregroundColor: ref.watch(foregroundColor),
          pinned: true,
          elevation: 0,
          title: const Text('We did it!'),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            const [
              SizedBox(height: 400),
              SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: Card(margin: EdgeInsets.all(16), color: Colors.blue),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 400),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final controller = Provider((ref) {
  final scrollController = ScrollController();
  void listener() {
    ref.read(backgroundOpacity.notifier).state = min(
      1,
      scrollController.position.pixels / 200,
    );
  }

  scrollController.addListener(listener);
  ref.onDispose(() {
    scrollController.removeListener(listener);
  });
  return scrollController;
});

final backgroundColor = Provider(
  (ref) => Colors.black.withOpacity(
    ref.watch(backgroundOpacity),
  ),
);

final foregroundColor = Provider(
  (ref) => Color.fromRGBO(
    (ref.watch(backgroundOpacity) * 255).toInt(),
    (ref.watch(backgroundOpacity) * 255).toInt(),
    (ref.watch(backgroundOpacity) * 255).toInt(),
    1,
  ),
);

final backgroundOpacity = StateProvider((_) => 0.0);
```

I also wrote the sample that works on DartPad.

If you like please try this.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=336910211bb02227e4c0b11e939aa116